# Permission Denied! when install extension in opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: opencart, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I have install extension **"newsletter"** and **"simple blog"** on opencart

2.3.0.2 add permission in **user/user_group** then also. when i try to enable the  status it will display **"Permission Denied!"** message and

doesn't allow me to display this module. But same module working fine
 one previous opencart 2.2.X and one get same problem and got solution?

if this is due to compatibility problem where i can change the
 permission in code of module.

is any one know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about maintaining a web app rather than programming. This should probably be asked through Opencart's own support channels.

Comment: In opencart 2302 module directory has changed, look for your module files, are there in correct directory? Can you provide modules download link?

Comment: i have use https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=18315&filter_search=simple%20blog&filter_license=free

Comment: This module is not Compatible with 2.3.0.2

Comment: ya it is compatible for 2.0 but it still work on 2.2 so is there any modification on module where we can set the permission?

Comment: @SamirKarmacharya Is there any solution you found for this solution yet. I'm really helpless here.

Comment: ya i have change all file location and modify files according to 2.3.X and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings>Users>User Groups than choose which user group your admin belongs to.
You will see "Access Permissions" and "Modify Permissions". Click the "check all" link for both permission group, than save.
You are good to go :)

Comment: Worked for me. I added all the permissions to the Administrator. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the module installation does not allow you to set user group rights. You can do this manually.

- Login to you PHPMyAdmin
- Go to table oc_user_group
- Edit user group ID 1
- Add and instance of your extension by the following example 
  extension/module/modulename
- Save
- Go to module in admin section

Comment: In data base  group id =1  and name =Administrator in permission field it display the module name too. but it didn't work

Comment: Perhaps these modules require write access to a directory of database table. Is there an error in the log?

Answer (score 0):

Forget adjusting tables
You don't need to change anything in your database to fix this issue

Here is an example from an older version controller:
Code: Select all

```
        $this->redirect($this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
```

It should now be written as:
Code: Select all

```
        $this->redirect($this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
```

So if you have an old module check your controller i.e. admin/controller/module/yourmodule.php
then find 'extension/module'
replace 'extension/extension'

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->user>->hasPermission( 'modify', extension/extension);
```